# Get class/module name

Tags: ruby

Is there a better way to get class/module name viz, `C` from `A::B::C`, `B` from `A::B::C`, and `A` From `A::B::C`. The following code uses string and split to get `"Stegosaurus"` from `Cowsay::Character::Stegosaurus`, How to do away with string and split?

```
require 'cowsay'
x = Cowsay.random_character().class
x.name.split("::")[2]
require 'cowsay'
true
x = Cowsay.random_character().class
Cowsay::Character::Stegosaurus
x.name.split("::")[2]
"Stegosaurus"
```

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that you wish to extract each element without converting `A::B::C` to a string? Note that in this example `A` is a module, but `B` and `C` are not modules, not even Ruby objects, so the best you could do is `A` or `"A"`, and `"B"` and `"C"`. Since you are ending up with strings anyway, why avoid converting  `A::B::C` to a string, as what you have is a very easy way to do it?

Comment: If I was not clear in my comment above, `A::B::C` tells us there are three nested modules, `A`, `A::B` and `A::B::C`. `B` and `C` are not modules.  If you defined modules `A::C` and `B::C`, what would it mean to refer to module `C`?

Comment: IMO `split("::")[2]` is not that bad. Certainly not as bad as requiring activesupport. It is simple and does the job.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there's anything for handling this in core/standard library.

As an alternative to custom written methods there is always `activesupport`:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/string/inflections'
Cowsay::Character::Stegosaurus.name.demodulize
#=> "Stegosaurus"
Cowsay::Character::Stegosaurus.name.deconstantize
#=> "Cowsay::Character"
```

These methods are implemented as follows:

```
def demodulize(path)
  path = path.to_s
  if i = path.rindex('::')
    path[(i+2)..-1]
  else
    path
  end
end

def deconstantize(path)
  path.to_s[0, path.rindex('::') || 0] # implementation based on the one in facets' Module#spacename
end
```

Take a look [into docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-demodulize) if interested in more methods.

As to

> `A` From `A::B::C`

If you'd `require` the whole `activesupport`, you'd get bunch of `Module` methods, including [`parent`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-parent):

```
require 'active_support'
Cowsay::Character::Stegosaurus.parent
#=> Cowsay
```

If you're not going to use  it extensively, I recommend to just grab the needed methods from `activesupport` and put it into some helper, because loading it whole might be an overkill.

Comment: Good point about extracting the useful methods if you need them. That's what's great about having open-source: You can always borrow parts if you need them.